# Literal [] in Thymeleaf Text Template

Tags: thymeleaf

Is there a way, within a "TEXT" mode template, to output something like:

```
Foo [1]
```

Based off of a variable?

Something like this doesn't seem to parse correctly:

```
Foo [[(${foo})]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These work, depending on your formatting preference:

```
-- using string concatenation
Foo [(${'[' + foo + ']'})]

-- using literal substitution
Foo [(|[${foo}]|)]

-- more verbose
Foo [# th:text="${'[' + foo + ']'}" /]
Foo [# th:text="|[${foo}]|" /]
```